# How do I remove click animation from a TextButton widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

```
 TextButton CameraOpeningButton() {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        initCamera();
      },
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage('assets/SVG/CameraButton.png'),
        height: 70,
        width: 70,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This image represents what happens when the button is clicked. A blue animation comes till the button is clicked. And I want to remove it.
[image: This Blue background is to be removed from the button]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 TextButton CameraOpeningButton() {
return TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    initCamera();
  },
 style: ButtonStyle(
        splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory, // this line will help you
      ),
  child: Image(
    image: AssetImage('assets/SVG/CameraButton.png'),
    height: 70,
    width: 70,
  ),
);
}
}
```

**EDIT:**
to make the button circular use this code:

```
style: ButtonStyle(
                        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                          CircleBorder(),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: Can you suggest me some way of changing is shape to circular.

Comment: check out the code now i updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code snippet inside your `TextButton` instance

```dart
style: const ButtonStyle(
  splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory
),
```